# ¿Como puedo realizar un filtrador de busqueda con PHP?

Tags: php, php8

estoy creando una web de bienes raices, todo bien, el problema es que quiero añadir un buscador con filtrador de propiedades, pero no por mas que intento no lo logro, actualmente mi codigo que muestra propiedades es simple; muestra resultados por paginas pero quiero añadirle un filtrador que muestre los resultados paginados en la misma pagina, algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo normal con paginador sin lo que necesito, como antes lo menciono:

```
                            <?php 
                            if(!empty($_REQUEST["nume"])){ $_REQUEST["nume"] = $_REQUEST["nume"];}else{ $_REQUEST["nume"] = '1';}
                            if($_REQUEST["nume"] == "" ){$_REQUEST["nume"] = "1";}
                            $articulos=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM propiedades WHERE tipo = '1' AND visible = 'Visible' ORDER BY created;");
                            $num_registros=@mysqli_num_rows($articulos);
                            $registros= '9';
                            $pagina=$_REQUEST["nume"];
                            if (is_numeric($pagina))
                            $inicio= (($pagina-1)*$registros);
                            else// el locate esta funcionado, pero al agregar tambien el created lo caga todo xd ah xd deja investigo algo
                            $inicio=0; # Match columns: CIUDAD, RENTA O VENTA, MASCOTAS, ROOMIES, HIJOS
                            $busqueda = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM propiedades WHERE tipo = '1' AND visible = 'Visible'
                                ORDER BY created DESC
                                LIMIT $inicio, $registros;
                            ");
                            $paginas=ceil($num_registros/$registros);

                            // Obtener propiedades por orden de matching del pefil del usuario
                            $propiedades_fetch = getPropertiesByProfileMatching($busqueda);
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($propiedades_fetch as $key => $propiedadrr){ ?>
                            <div class="listing-item">
                                <article class="geodir-category-listing fl-wrap">
                                    <div class="geodir-category-img fl-wrap">
                                        <a href="/propiedad/<?php echo $propiedadrr['id'];?>" class="geodir-category-img_item">
                                            <?php $images = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id2 = ".$propiedadrr['id']." LIMIT 1");
                                            while ($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($images)) {
                                            ?>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $web_settings['weblink'];?>uploads/<?php echo $image['file_name'];?>" alt="" style="height: 310px;">
                                            <?php } ?>
                                            <div class="overlay"></div>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="geodir-category-location">
                                                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> <span>  <?php echo $propiedadrr['calle'];?>, <?php echo $propiedadrr['ciudad'];?></span></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul class="list-single-opt_header_cat">
                                                <li><a href="#" class="cat-opt blue-bg"><?php if ($propiedadrr['tipo'] == 1) {
                                                    echo 'Venta';
                                                }?><?php if ($propiedadrr['tipo'] == 2) {
                                                    echo 'Renta';
                                                }?></a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#" class="cat-opt color-bg"><?php echo $propiedadrr['tipo_p'];?></a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        <div class="geodir-category-listing_media-list">
                                                <span><i class="fas fa-camera"></i> <?php if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id2 = ".$propiedadrr['id']." ORDER BY id")) { $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result); printf($row_cnt); mysqli_free_result($result); } ?></span>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="geodir-category-content fl-wrap">
                                            <h3 class="title-sin_item"><a href="/propiedad/<?php echo $propiedadrr['id'];?>"><?php echo $limitar = substr($propiedadrr['nombre'],0,29) . '...';?></a></h3>
                                            <div class="geodir-category-content_price"><?php if ($propiedadrr['enganche'] == 'yes') { ?> ENGANCHE DESDE <?php } ?>$<?php echo number_format($propiedadrr['precio']);?> <?php echo $propiedadrr['moneda'];?></div>
                                            <div class="geodir-category-content-details" style="border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;padding-top: 15px;margin-top:5px;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><i class="fal fa-bed"></i><span><?php echo $propiedadrr['recamaras'];?></span></li>
                                                    <li><i class="fal fa-bath"></i><span><?php echo $propiedadrr['banos'];?></span></li>
                                                    <li><i class="fal fa-car"></i><span><?php echo $propiedadrr['estacionamiento'];?></span></li>
                                                    <?php 
                                                    if ($propiedadrr['metros2'] >= 1) {
                                                        echo '<li><i class="fal fa-cube"></i><span>'.$propiedadrr['metros2'].' m2</span></li>';
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="geodir-category-footer fl-wrap">
                                                <?php $authors = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = ".$propiedadrr['author']." LIMIT 1");
                                                    while ($author = mysqli_fetch_assoc($authors)) {
                                                    ?>
                                                <a href="/perfil/<?php echo $author['id'];?>" class="gcf-company">
                                                    <?php if ($author['foto_perfil'] == 0) {
                                                    echo '<img src="/images/default_profile.jpg" alt="">';
                                                    } ?>
                                                    <img src="/uploads/profile_fotos/<?php echo $author['foto_perfil'];?>">
                                                    <span><?php echo $author['nombres'];?></span>
                                                </a>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </article>
                            </div>
                            <!-- listing-item end-->
                            <?php } if(mysqli_num_rows($busqueda) == 0) { ?>
                            <h1>No hay propiedades en venta aún...</h1>
                            <?php } ?>          
                        </div>
                        <!-- listing-item-wrap end-->
                        <!-- pagination-->
                        <div class="pagination">
                            <?php
                            if($_REQUEST["nume"] == "1" ){
                            $_REQUEST["nume"] == "0";
                            echo  "";
                            }else{
                            if ($pagina>1)
                            $ant = $_REQUEST["nume"] - 1;
                            echo "<a href='?nume=1' class='prevposts-link'><i class='fa fa-caret-left'></i></a>"; 
                            echo "<a href='?nume=". ($pagina-1) ."' >".$ant."</a>"; }
                            echo "<a class='current-page'>".$_REQUEST["nume"]."</a>"; 
                            $sigui = $_REQUEST["nume"] + 1;
                            $ultima = $num_registros / $registros;
                            if ($ultima == $_REQUEST["nume"] +1 ){
                            $ultima == "";}
                            if ($pagina<$paginas && $paginas>1)
                            echo "<a href='?nume=". ($pagina+1) ."' class='nextposts-link'>".$sigui."</a>"; 
                            if ($pagina<$paginas && $paginas>1)
                            echo "<a href='?nume=". ceil($ultima) ."' class='nextposts-link'><i class='fa fa-caret-right'></i></a>";
                            ?>
                        </div>
```

he mirado videos en youtube, codigos pero no puedo lograr hacer algo asi, espero me puedan orientar